# Windows 10 image backup

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-backup, backup

I have a PC that has a 500 GB internal SSD system letter C Drive, an old internal 120 GB SSD letter P drive, a 1-TB internal letter D drive and an external 1 TB letter G drive. I'd like to backup just the C drive. 
By default, the backup process wants to put my backup on the G external drive.

[image]

When I try to create an image of my C drive using Windows 7 Backup on Windows 10, if I try to place the backup on my D drive, it tells me that I should not save a backup to one of the drives that is being backed up. Apparently, the "system image" includes backing up the D.

[image]

So, I decide to place the backup on the G drive. After creating the backup on the G drive and then rebooting from an old Windows Recovery disk that I created, I lose visibility to the external G drive where my backup image was placed. However, it does see the D drive.

How do I know/select which drives are part of the "system image?" I would have expected it to only be C or alternatively let me determine which drives I wanted to back up.

To make matters worse, when upgrading to Windows 10, my memorex MRX-550L DVD drive is no longer visible in Windows 10. I have no "warnings" in the Device Manager and no detected device to upgrade the driver. However, as mentioned above, I can boot from a Windows Recovery CD still. I was unable to locate any driver for device. I created a ticket with Memorex and they told me that the drive was distributed by Imation and to check with them. I found nothing on the Imation site and entered a Support Ticket there, too. Upgrading the Chipset Driver software for my mother board did not help.

I never successfully restored a backup system image before. I tried it once and it failed with a non specific error after running for a long period of time. I just installed Windows 7 to a refresh drive, installed all of the latest patches and then upgraded online to Windows 10 and now I'd like to made a nice image of where I am since this seems like a nice place to recover back to but I am not sure how to proceed.

I want to make an image backup of my C drive and then restore from the image to see if it works. What should I do? If I back up to D, which drives am I backing up? Can I limit it to only C? Why can't I recover from the backup image of G? Did I miss an option to include additional drivers on my recover disk? Since my DVD is no longer usable, I seem to be in a jam to try creating another recovery disk to try again.